# JavaScript focus on google earth plugin

Tags: javascript, google-earth-plugin

I Have a `div` section named 'MapPanel' in which I defined the Google Earth Plug-in.

I have a form next to it and I wish that on a certain event the "focus" of the web page will be on the Google earth so that for example that I can move the map with the arrows.

I have tried `$("#MapPanel").focus()` without success.

Comment: Maybe try to focus on an element inside this MapPanel? If you had a code example it would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [GEWindow object](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_g_e_window) has a [focus() method](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_g_e_window#a13747d4faf5226f752ea7935cde10c8b) for this purpose.
You would call it like so, where `ge` represents the [GEPlugin object](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_g_e_plugin).

```
ge.getWindow().focus();
```